# How do I rename files by moving the first 4 numbers

Tags: finder

How do I rename files by moving the first 4 characters (numbers in my case) in file name to the end of the filename using A Better Finder Renamer?

Answer (score 1):

I made an example scenario in Better Finder Rename 10 <sup><sub>(10.20)</sub></sup>

My filenames:

```
0001 - Example.svg
0002 - Example.svg
0003 - Example.svg
0004 - Example.svg
0005 - Example.svg
0006 - Example.svg
0007 - Example.svg
0008 - Example.svg
0009 - Example.svg
0010 - Example.svg
0011 - Example.svg
0012 - Example.svg
```

I used the `Multi-step drawer` to do this, since I wanted to also clean up the new filename so that there is a space between the numbers once they are at the end and I also wanted to remove the `-` in the front, since it wouldn't be needed anymore.

---

First I add a space to the end in preparation of the numbers:

> This is its own step

- Category: `Text`
- Action: `Add text to end`
- Add:  <sup><sub><- a single space</sub></sup>
- Change: `The filename without the extension`

[image]

Then I move the numbers to the end:

> This is its own step

- Category: `Character Positions & Ranges`
- Action: `Move a range of characters to position`
- **From text position**: `0`, `From the front`
- **A number of characters**: `Next`, `4`
- To text position: `0`, `From the end`
- Change: `Only the file name`

[image]

...and all that is left is to remove the spacer I had between the numbers and the text `-`:

> This is its own step

- Category: `Text`
- Action: `Remove text from beginning`
- Remove: `-` <sup><sub><- space dash space</sub></sup>
- Change: `The file name without the extension`

[image]